# How to make multiple keys in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make multiple keys to press but the command focus_set() makes only one button available to press, the rest of the keys doesnt work. The button works if you click it but I want to use the button through the keyboard so how do I make so every key works

```
btnUp = tkinter.Button(master=None, text="Up", command=up)
btnUp.bind("w", up)
btnUp.focus_set()
btnUp.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, anchor=tkinter.W)

btnRight = tkinter.Button(master=None, text="Right", command=right)
btnRight.bind("d", right)
btnRight.focus_set()
btnRight.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, anchor=tkinter.W)

btnLeft = tkinter.Button(master=None, text="Left", command=left)
btnLeft.bind("a", left)
btnLeft.focus_set()
btnLeft.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, anchor=tkinter.W)

btnDown = tkinter.Button(master=None, text="Down", command=down)
btnDown.bind("s", down)
btnDown.focus_set()
btnDown.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM, anchor=tkinter.W)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind to the widget that the Buttons are in. For the most effectiveness, bind to root.

```
btnUp = tkinter.Button(master=None, text="Up", command=up)
root.bind("w", up)
btnUp.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, anchor=tkinter.W)
```

If you don't have access to root in that scope you can add this to the top:

```
root = tkinter._default_root
```

---

Remember that the Button command callback and the bind callback have different signatures, so you need to define the functions with an optional event argument like this:

```
def up(event=None):
    # code
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    root.bind("w", up)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'

Comment: I don't mean at the top of your code, I mean at the top of whatever scope you are in. You'll need to show a [mcve] for more specific help.

Comment: Oh okay, I changed the placement of the code line and it worked! Thank you so much!